# Accessing birthday and email with Facebook API using OAuth access

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-fql

I'm using OAuth to access Facebook API.
Scope parameter contains `email, user_activities, user_birthday`.

I'm doing FQL query `SELECT email, birthday, activities FROM user WHERE uid = me()`.
I've tried to execute this query with several accounts with this fields marked as public.
Server's answer contains requested variables but they are empty.

Is it possible to get this information using OAuth access?

Comment: Are you passing the correct access_token to the FQL query?

Comment: i am not sure about FQL ,but if you can Get request  https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,birthday  along with access token.

Comment: Yes, I'm passing correct access_token. I can get information like name, location, etc. But the problem is with email, birthday and activities.

Comment: @AntonSamsungovichPervomaysky "name" for example does not require a valid access_token at all to get, while all 3 that you have problems with do.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell for sure without seeing the complete code, but if you're getting empty answers for those 3 fields, it would seem you're not passing the an access_token with the correct permissions to the FQL query;

> Permissions
>
> To read the user table you need
>
> - no access_token for publicly available data: uid, name, first_name,
>     middle_name, last_name, sex, locale, pic_small_with_logo,
>     pic_big_with_logo, pic_square_with_logo, pic_with_logo, username
> - any valid access_token for additional user data, except for the follow-on
>     exceptions:
>     ** ...
>     ** email permissions to view: proxied_email, contact_email
>     ** user_birthday or friends_birthday permissions to view: birthday, birthday_date
>     ** ...
>     ** user_activities or friends_activities permissions to view: activities

I'm not sure how you're authenticating using OAuth, but for as how to get the correct access token and permissions, you can start looking [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/)